# Open Outlook Web App calender in new tab

Tags: outlook-on-the-web

I'm forced to use the Outlook Web App at work... To make it easier to switch between emails and the calendar, I would like to open each in its own tab.

Simply opening a new tab and going to the page doesn't work since it says:

> There was a problem opening your mailbox. You may have already signed in to Outlook Web App on a different browser tab. If so, close this tab and return to the other tab. If that doesn't work, you can try:
>
> - Closing your browser window and signing in again.
> - Deleting cookies from your browser and signing in again.

Is there a work-around?

Answer (score 2):

It just occured to me that I can open a private browsing session and login again. That gives me two independent browsers so I can keep different parts of the web app open in each.

It's not ideal, though, since I have to login again and since I would prefer to have two tabs in a single browser window.

Answer (score 0):

This approach worked for me . . .

1. Copy your Outlook Web App URL from your address bar
2. Open a new tab
3. Paste the URL into the new tab
4. Change the end of the URL from /mail to /calendar